# How to recover List Items from Recycle bin using Powershell by having item Guid

Tags: powershell, list-item, recycle-bin

With following code I have recycled list items and have stored item `GUID` in `$DeletedItem`:

```
for($i=$ListItems.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
     write-host "Deleted List Item with ID:$($ListItems[$i].ID)"
     $DeletedItem= $ListItems[$i].recycle()
}
```

I want to recover the items by using saved item's `GUIDs`, Is that possible? How I recover list items using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

Assuming `$DeletedItem = $ListItem.recycle()`:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://server/sites/site
$site.RecycleBin.Restore($DeletedItem)
```

Put it into a foreach cycle and you'll be able to restore a collection of items:
Assuming `$DeletedItems` is a collection of GUIDs:

```
ForEach ($deletedGuid in $DeletedItems)
{
    $site.RecycleBin.Restore($deletedGuid)
}
```